# How to create a json file with jq

Tags: json, jq

Now I am trying to make a json file.
I found an example which is with jq.

```
echo "$(jq -n '{Test1: $ARGS.named}' \
  --arg one 'Apple' \
  --arg two 'Banana')" >> config.json
```

I can get the result and save it into config.json

```
{
  "Test1": {
    "one": "Apple",
    "two": "Banana"
  }
}
```

Now, how to make the following result and save it.

```
{
  "Test1": {
    "one": "Apple",
    "two": "Banana"
  },
  "Test2": {
    "one": "Kiwi",
    "two": "Tomato"
  }  
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What are the rules for creating your file? TBH I don't think you need jq for this (not even for the first one). Simply use string interpolation in yuor shell

Comment: Can you share more details about your specific use case? Right now, I feel there could be indefinitely equally-good answers given

Comment: Instead of `echo "$(jq …)" > file`, just use `jq … > file`.

Comment: e.g. `echo '{"Test1":{"one":"Apple","two":"Banana"},"Test2":{"one":"Kiwi","two":"Tomato"}}' > config.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without creating a temporary file, assuming your shell is POSIX-based:

```bash
{
  jq -cn  --arg one 'Apple' --arg two 'Banana' '{Test1: $ARGS.named}'
  jq -cn  --arg one 'Kiwi'  --arg two 'Tomato' '{Test2: $ARGS.named}'
} | jq -s add > output.json
```

Or

```bash
jq -n \
   --argjson Test1 "$(jq -n --arg one 'Apple' --arg two 'Banana' '$ARGS.named')" \
   --argjson Test2 "$(jq -n --arg one 'Kiwi'  --arg two 'Tomato' '$ARGS.named')" \
  '$ARGS.named' > output.json
```

---

If this is a prelude to a list of "TestN" objects, we'll get a bit more programmitic, here with bash syntax:

```bash
ones=( Apple Kiwi )
twos=( Banana Tomato )

for ((i=0; i < ${#ones[@]}; i++)); do
  jq -cn \
     --arg one "${ones[i]}" \
     --arg two "${twos[i]}" \
     --arg key "Test$((i + 1))" \
     '{($key): {$one, $two}}'
done | jq -s add > output.json
```

---

Or, use a different tool: [jo](https://github.com/jpmens/jo)

```bash
jo Test1="$(jo one=Apple two=Banana)" Test2="$(jo one=Kiwi two=Tomato)"
```

```json
{"Test1":{"one":"Apple","two":"Banana"},"Test2":{"one":"Kiwi","two":"Tomato"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a JSON file:

```bash
$ jq -n --arg one 'Apple' --arg two 'Banana' \
  '{Test1: $ARGS.named}' > config.json
```

View the JSON file:

```bash
$ cat config.json
{
  "Test1": {
    "one": "Apple",
    "two": "Banana"
  }
}
```

Create another JSON file based on the first one (using jq's `.` for the input object, and `+` to add (merge) two objects):

```bash
$ jq --arg one 'Kiwi' --arg two 'Tomato' \
  '. + {Test2: $ARGS.named}' config.json > config2.json
```

View that other JSON file:

```bash
$ cat config2.json
{
  "Test1": {
    "one": "Apple",
    "two": "Banana"
  },
  "Test2": {
    "one": "Kiwi",
    "two": "Tomato"
  }
}
```

Overwrite the first one with the second one:

```bash
$ mv config2.json config.json
```

Now the first one has the content of the second one:

```
$ cat config.json
{
  "Test1": {
    "one": "Apple",
    "two": "Banana"
  },
  "Test2": {
    "one": "Kiwi",
    "two": "Tomato"
  }
}
```